# unexpected token: 'findlabel' at line 13 column 27

Tags: apex

What is going wrong here? I get this error:

> unexpected token: 'findlabel' at line 13 column 27

```
public class listapex {
    public list<selectoption> std {get;set;}
    public string val{get;set;}
    public listapex(){
            std= new list<selectoption>();
            selectoption s1= new selectoption('Null','--None--');
            selectoption s2= new selectoption('one','jan');
            std.add(s1);
            std.add(s2);
            std.add(new selectoption('two','feb'));
            std.add(new selectoption('three','mar'));
            }         
     public pagereference void findlabel()
     {
          for (selectoption s1 : std)
          {
                   if (s1.getvalue() == val)
                   {
                      val=s1.getlabel();
                   }
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not a valid method declaration

```
public pagereference void findlabel() {
```

You should declare the return type as EITHER void or PageReference

e.g. if the function will return a pagereference, use

```
public pagereference findlabel() {
```

or if it will return nothing use:

```
public void findlabel() {
```